# Winston logger with chrome extension tool

Tags: javascript, winston

I am trying to implement Winston logger with my chrome extension tool. I am not able to do it.

Also I am not very familiar with Node.js and npm.

Comment: Please include whatever you have done so far to the question

Answer (score 1):

Winston doesn't work in a browser context, so this isn't reasonably possible until that's fixed.

https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/287

Comment: So is there any Library which I can use for logging for chrome extension?

Comment: @SourabhRoy Sure, many.  But, who knows what to suggest to you as you haven't mentioned what your requirements are.

Comment: I have chrome extension tool which is completely developed using javascript. Now i want the js files to have loggers and these logs should be saved in some files. Please let me know if I made my requirement clear or do you want any more information from me

Comment: @SourabhRoy Saved in files, where?  Server-side?  Client-side?

Comment: on the client side... i mean on my machine for instance